# YouTube lagging in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: amd-graphics, youtube

I have an issue with YouTube and facebook videos 
There is lagging every 50 seconds or less
My specs are:
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
GPU: AMD Radeon R5 M330
RAM: 12GB
I tried everything....
the same issue is on Chrome, Firefox, Opera
Any solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your system specs? (ram) Please edit your question to include this

Comment: CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
RAM: 12GB

Comment: Have you turned on hardware acceleration in chrome? That might solve your problem. Refer to this article for instructions: https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122

Comment: I turned it on... the same issue.

it is also the same problem in Firefox and Opera
not only in Chrome

Comment: @MohmoudZidan Maybe disabling this flag (if its available for your computer) might solve your problem: chrome://flags/#enable-color-correct-rendering

Comment: You can also try to decrease swappiness. See here: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-swappiness/

Comment: @Idias I have the same issue, my specs: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/fXwCz7
this issue appears a couple of days ago. before, running fine. Is not an issue only for chrome. spotify music also suffer from this.

Comment: related info: https://dragoshmocrii.com/ubuntu-20-04-stuttering-animations-video/ that did not worked for me.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/gnome-shell-performance-improvements-in-ubuntu-20-04/15972/44
https://news.softpedia.com/news/fix-for-gnome-3-36-stuttering-bug-in-the-works-529842.shtml
still no solution for me.